# How to call multiple sql statements using jdbc template in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sequence

I want to get n values of a sequence at once from SQL server. I am able to achieve this using the below list of SQL queries:

```
DECLARE @FirstSeqNum sql_variant, @LastSeqNum sql_variant; 
  
EXEC sys.sp_sequence_get_range  
@sequence_name = N'SERVICEVRSNS.CountBy1'  
, @range_size = 100  
, @range_first_value = @FirstSeqNum OUTPUT   
, @range_last_value = @LastSeqNum OUTPUT ;  
  
-- The following statement returns the output values  
SELECT  
  @FirstSeqNum AS FirstVal  
, @LastSeqNum AS LastVal ;
```

The output looks something like this:

| FirstVal | SecondVal |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 200 |

Every time I trigger the above SQL list, it gives the range.

Can I achieve the same using **one SQL statement** to get the range something like this:

```
 private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
      jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Map<String,Object>.class);
```

Note: I don't want to create a stored procedure or call the system stored procedure.

Comment: The obvious thing would be to call `sys.sp_sequence_get_range` directly from JDBC. It's not clear why you're wanting to avoid that.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning . I am using jdbc template to get the sequence like this
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class);
Here you see the sql formed to get the sequence might not be specific to sql server it can be anything that why